Exporting CosmosDB Data as CSV
Is there a way to export CosmosDB data to CSV? Or even a json file? I don't see any direct way from the portal and I believe the feature was disabled from Azure Storage Explorer.

Yes, you can export it to JSON via the Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL connector for Azure Data Factory.  Also see this link.
Kind of a heavyweight solution, but it is a way to do it.
